# Can I dynamically pass a list of arguments to a python function with predefined arguments?

Tags: python

I have a python function `bar(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None, e=None)`. I was wondering if it was possible to build the list of arguments I want to pass in, with a list or a string, or something.

I would have a list of attributes to look for and ideally I would simply loop over them and build the argument string.

For example, something like:

```
dict = {'a' : 5, 'c' : 3, 'd' :9} 
arg_string = ""
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    arg_string += "{0}={1},".format(k, v)

bar(arg_string)
```

In this case I don't have any values to pass in for b and e, but the next time the program runs there may be.

Is this possible?

**I know the string being built in the for loop will probably be invalid because of the comma at the end. But i didn't think it was necessary to write the handling for that**

Comment: The comma wouldn't be the problem, rather that you are calling `bar("a=5, c=3, d=9")` instead of `bar(a=5, c=3, d=9)`.

Comment: And, FWIW, trailing commas in python function calls are actually permissable (though ugly) -- `foo(a, b, c,)` is a syntactically valid function call.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The good news is that you don't even need a string. . .

```
mapping = {'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 9} 
bar(**mapping)
```

should work.  See the [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (and surrounding material) in the official python tutorial.

Comment: Works like a charm with variable values as well, for instance I use it with mongoengine and I don't know the db value to update, so I handle it dynamically via `mapping = {dbEntry: value}
    myDBcollection.update(**mapping)`
`dbEntry` can anything like `name`,`price`,`symbol`, etc